# How to get some values of sublists with the values of 2 other lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I declared `letters`, which one has more sublists and I declared `row` and `columns`.
What I want to do is to get some values of `letters` with the values of `row` and `column`. For example I want the value that `letters` has in row[0] (which one is `0`) and column[0] (which one is `2`), so I have to repit the process again in `letters` with row[1] (which one is `2`) and column[1] (which one is `1`). So at the final when I print `finalOutput` it should display in console `['C', 'R']`.
Excuse me if my explanation is bad, but you can guide you with the final result.

I have written this:

```
letters = [['letters1', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'BUILD'], ['letter2','F', 'P', 'Z', 'W', 'SHOW', 'BUILD'], ['leters3','R', 'X', 'N', 'BUILD', 'SHOW']]

row = [0, 2]
columns = [2, 1]

finalOutput = []
    
for i in range(len(letters)):
    for j in range(len(letters[i])):
        finalOutput.append(letters[row[i]][columns[j]])
print(finalOutput)
```

But with this code I have the next error `IndexError: list index out of range` and obviously I don´t have the output that I mentioned before.

I hope someone could help me, thanks!

Comment: Eduardo, you need to think about what a list index is.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the indices in the row and column lists will always be less than the length of letters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your nested for loop, the for statements should iterate over your elements in `row` and `columns` (so starting with `row[0]` and `columns[0]`, then `row[1]` and `columns[1]`).

What it's doing right now is iterating over every element in `letters`, so it breaks when `i = 0` and `j = 2` - this doesn't exist in `row` and `columns`, but is a valid coordinate in `letters`.

What you want is something like this:

```
for i in range(len(row)):
    finalOutput.append(letters[row[i]][columns[i]])
print(finalOutput)
```

This iterates through your targeted row-column combinations, instead of every element in `letters`.